# async.queue does not drain when Read ECONNRESET error occurs

Tags: async.js

I am using async.queue to make calls to microsoft graph APIs. Whenever code enters the if(err) block, the queue does not drain. The error that occurs almost always when it enters if(err) block is Read ECONNRESET.
Please find code below:

```
function asyncDataPull(url, callback) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    request.get({
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            displayName: getName(url)
        }
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }
        else if (!body) {
            callback();
        }
        else if(typeof(JSON.parse(body)['error']) != "undefined") {
            callback();
        } else if(typeof(JSON.parse(body).value) != "undefined"){
            callback();                                 
        }
        else{
            callback();                
        }

    })
}
var q = async.queue(asyncDataPull, 100);
for (var userIndex = 0; userIndex < users.length; userIndex++) {
    q.push('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + users[userIndex].mail + '/messages');
    q.push('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + users[userIndex].mail + '/events');
    q.push('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + users[userIndex].mail + '/calendarView');
}
q.drain = function(){
  console.log("all tasks have completed");
}
```

I am pushing dynamically back into the queue in couple of if-else conditions. Will include this code if required.

Comment: Hi Vipin, I'm not sure about that error logic, but I did notice you're sending a displayName header field. Do you know what that's for/where it's documented? I don't think I've seen that used in Graph API before.

Comment: We also support JSON batching that might simplify this logic. The idea is you can make one REST request to graph that does multiple calls, like getting a users calendar and messages.  You'll have to do more JSON parsing but it should make the network requests much faster. Documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching